# Occurence of certain date is more than x times, get next available date

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe containing 15 columns, 1 column  is the participant ID and the 14 columns of possible appointment dates per participant (excluding holidays and weekends):

```
  Included.Participant         V1         V2         V3         V4         V5   V6   V7         V8         V9        V10        V11        V12  V13  V14
1                    1 2021-03-22 2021-03-23 2021-03-24 2021-03-25 2021-03-26 <NA> <NA> 2021-03-29 2021-03-30 2021-03-31 2021-04-01 2021-04-02 <NA> <NA>
2                    2 2021-03-22 2021-03-23 2021-03-24 2021-03-25 2021-03-26 <NA> <NA> 2021-03-29 2021-03-30 2021-03-31 2021-04-01 2021-04-02 <NA> <NA>
3                    3 2021-03-22 2021-03-23 2021-03-24 2021-03-25 2021-03-26 <NA> <NA> 2021-03-29 2021-03-30 2021-03-31 2021-04-01 2021-04-02 <NA> <NA>
4                    4 2021-03-22 2021-03-23 2021-03-24 2021-03-25 2021-03-26 <NA> <NA> 2021-03-29 2021-03-30 2021-03-31 2021-04-01 2021-04-02 <NA> <NA>
5                    5 2021-03-22 2021-03-23 2021-03-24 2021-03-25 2021-03-26 <NA> <NA> 2021-03-29 2021-03-30 2021-03-31 2021-04-01 2021-04-02 <NA> <NA>
6                    6 2021-03-22 2021-03-23 2021-03-24 2021-03-25 2021-03-26 <NA> <NA> 2021-03-29 2021-03-30 2021-03-31 2021-04-01 2021-04-02 <NA> <NA>
```

Per date, 3 participants can be added. If a maximum of 3 has been reached, it should move to the next available date for the fourth participant. So in this example the desired output would be:

```
      Included.Participant         V1
1                    1 2021-03-22
2                    2 2021-03-22
3                    3 2021-03-22
4                    4 2021-03-23
5                    5 2021-03-23
6                    6 2021-03-23
```

If there is no possible date left then column V1 can stay empty.

I cannot seem to figure out how to get the desired output.. I really hope you can help out

Many thanks!

dput:

```
structure(list(Included.y = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L), 
    V1 = structure(c(18870, NA, 18848, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18806, 
    18799, 18835, 18841, NA, NA, 18912, 18954, NA, 18842, NA, 
    NA), class = "Date"), V2 = structure(c(18871, NA, 18849, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 18876, 18807, 18800, 18836, 18842, NA, NA, 
    18913, 18955, NA, 18843, NA, NA), class = "Date"), V3 = structure(c(18872, 
    18904, 18850, 18897, 18967, NA, 18883, 18877, 18808, 18801, 
    18837, 18843, 18890, NA, 18914, 18956, 18953, 18844, NA, 
    18869), class = "Date"), V4 = structure(c(NA, 18905, 18851, 
    18898, 18968, 18953, 18884, 18878, 18809, 18802, NA, 18844, 
    18891, 18967, NA, NA, 18954, NA, 18925, 18870), class = "Date"), 
    V5 = structure(c(NA, 18906, NA, 18899, 18969, 18954, 18885, 
    18879, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18892, 18968, NA, NA, 18955, NA, 18926, 
    18871), class = "Date"), V6 = structure(c(NA, 18907, NA, 
    18900, 18970, 18955, 18886, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18893, 18969, 
    NA, NA, 18956, NA, 18927, 18872), class = "Date"), V7 = structure(c(18876, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 18956, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18841, NA, NA, 18970, 
    18918, 18960, NA, 18848, 18928, NA), class = "Date"), V8 = structure(c(18877, 
    NA, 18855, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18813, 18806, 18842, 18848, 
    NA, NA, 18919, 18961, NA, 18849, NA, NA), class = "Date"), 
    V9 = structure(c(18878, NA, 18856, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18883, 
    18814, 18807, 18843, 18849, NA, NA, 18920, 18962, NA, 18850, 
    NA, NA), class = "Date"), V10 = structure(c(18879, 18911, 
    18857, 18904, 18974, NA, 18890, 18884, 18815, 18808, 18844, 
    18850, 18897, NA, 18921, 18963, 18960, 18851, NA, 18876), class = "Date"), 
    V11 = structure(c(NA, 18912, 18858, 18905, 18975, 18960, 
    18891, 18885, 18816, 18809, NA, 18851, 18898, 18974, NA, 
    NA, 18961, NA, 18932, 18877), class = "Date"), V12 = structure(c(NA, 
    18913, NA, 18906, 18976, 18961, 18892, 18886, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 18899, 18975, NA, NA, 18962, NA, 18933, 18878), class = "Date"), 
    V13 = structure(c(NA, 18914, NA, 18907, 18977, 18962, 18893, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18900, 18976, NA, NA, 18963, NA, 18934, 
    18879), class = "Date"), V14 = structure(c(18883, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 18963, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18848, NA, NA, 18977, 18925, 
    18967, NA, 18855, 18935, NA), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It would really help test and verify a solution if you could paste your data as objects into the question: use `dput(your_dataframe)`.

Comment: Once a date is filled with three participants say 2021-02-23 in `V1` is the same date: 2021-02-23 in `V2`  still available for other participants?

Comment: See my comment underneath your answer. Hope this clears this up

Comment: shouldn't the preference for `23-3-21` be given to 7th participant instead of 4th as it is her/his first choice as opposed to second choice of 4th?  Please clarify?

Comment: Hi, these are not dates based on preferencees. These are all the possibilities for appointments for that participant so we do not have to consider which dates are in which column number. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated code following clarification allocation of participants to same dates in different columns:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)


df1 <- 
  df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Included.Participant) %>% 
  select(-Included.Participant) %>% 
  mutate(name = factor(name, levels = paste0("V", 1:14), ordered = TRUE))%>% 
  group_by(value) %>%
  arrange(value, name) %>% 
  slice_head(n = 3)%>% 
  rowid_to_column(var = "Included.Participant") %>% 
  filter(Included.Participant <= 20) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)
```

- output

```
head(df1, 10)
#> # A tibble: 10 x 5
#>    Included.Participant V1         V2         V3         V4        
#>                   <int> <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>    
#>  1                    1 2021-03-22 NA         NA         NA        
#>  2                    2 2021-03-22 NA         NA         NA        
#>  3                    3 2021-03-22 NA         NA         NA        
#>  4                    4 2021-03-23 NA         NA         NA        
#>  5                    5 2021-03-23 NA         NA         NA        
#>  6                    6 2021-03-23 NA         NA         NA        
#>  7                    7 NA         2021-03-24 NA         NA        
#>  8                    8 NA         2021-03-24 NA         NA        
#>  9                    9 NA         2021-03-24 NA         NA        
#> 10                   10 NA         NA         2021-03-25 NA
```

Comment: Hi Peter, Thanks for your help. for the first 6 participants it seems to be the output I desire but from  participant 7 onwards, the immediate next possible date is not select. In row 7 the next available date is 2021-03-24. Also, if the date 2021-03-23 in the example already has 3 'slots' filled (by participants 4-6) then that date should not be available anymore. I added the dput of my exact output to the orgiinal post.

Comment: Code modified to reflect clarification.

Comment: Hi Peter, thank you so so much! This is exactly what i needed :D you made my day

Comment: Hi Peter, i just noticed that the ID column is replaced with the row numbers. Is there any way to keep the ID column as it is?

Comment: Which column is the ID column? None of the columns in the original dataframe are called "ID". Do you mean column `Included.Participant`; these values are integers, in effect row numbers.

Comment: Yes, sorry. It is the Included.Participant column. In this example, the rows are perfectly in order but in reality, some participants will be excluded and thus not end up in the Included.Participant column. Would it help if i added a new dput of a dataframe with several IDs missing?

Comment: Yes it would help to change the dataframe to reflect the data as is.

Comment: Hello Peter, I updated the dput in the original comment. Thanks so much

Comment: @Debbie, This is rather different now and will most likely require a different coding approach: I would suggest posting this as a fresh question including the rules for the output you require. And replace the original dataset for this question.

Comment: thanks. I posted something new. I was wondering however, is there really no way possible to include the Included.Participant in your solution? So after you order the dates that it recognizes which date belongs to which ID? Instead of `rowid_to_column(var = "Included.Participant")`, include the actual Included.Participant again?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230955/discussion-between-peter-and-debbie-oomen).