# Keep original ID column while creating data frame with date availabilities

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tibble

Via you guys I already got a great code for getting a dataframe of available dates based on the amount of participants per date: [Occurence of certain date is more than x times, get next available date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66903560/occurence-of-certain-date-is-more-than-x-times-get-next-available-date?noredirect=1#comment118266126_66903560)

However, I just noticed that within this dataframe, I am not keeping the original IDs of my participants but replacing them with row names in ascending order. However, I still need the IDs to check which participants belongs to which date. This is the code used to create this dataframe:

```
df1 <- 
  T0range %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Included.y) %>% 
  select(-Included.y) %>% 
  mutate(name = factor(name, levels = paste0("V", 1:14), ordered = TRUE))%>% 
  group_by(value) %>%
  arrange(value, name) %>% 
  slice_head(n = 12)%>% 
  rowid_to_column(var = "Included.y") %>% 
  filter(Included.y <= length(T0range$Included.y)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)
```

T0range looks like this:

dput
structure(list(Included.y = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L,
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L),
V1 = structure(c(18870, NA, 18848, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18806,
18799, 18835, 18841, NA, NA, 18912, 18954, NA, 18842, NA,
NA), class = "Date"), V2 = structure(c(18871, NA, 18849,
NA, NA, NA, NA, 18876, 18807, 18800, 18836, 18842, NA, NA,
18913, 18955, NA, 18843, NA, NA), class = "Date"), V3 = structure(c(18872,
18904, 18850, 18897, 18967, NA, 18883, 18877, 18808, 18801,
18837, 18843, 18890, NA, 18914, 18956, 18953, 18844, NA,
18869), class = "Date"), V4 = structure(c(NA, 18905, 18851,
18898, 18968, 18953, 18884, 18878, 18809, 18802, NA, 18844,
18891, 18967, NA, NA, 18954, NA, 18925, 18870), class = "Date"),
V5 = structure(c(NA, 18906, NA, 18899, 18969, 18954, 18885,
18879, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18892, 18968, NA, NA, 18955, NA, 18926,
18871), class = "Date"), V6 = structure(c(NA, 18907, NA,
18900, 18970, 18955, 18886, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18893, 18969,
NA, NA, 18956, NA, 18927, 18872), class = "Date"), V7 = structure(c(18876,
NA, NA, NA, NA, 18956, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18841, NA, NA, 18970,
18918, 18960, NA, 18848, 18928, NA), class = "Date"), V8 = structure(c(18877,
NA, 18855, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18813, 18806, 18842, 18848,
NA, NA, 18919, 18961, NA, 18849, NA, NA), class = "Date"),
V9 = structure(c(18878, NA, 18856, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18883,
18814, 18807, 18843, 18849, NA, NA, 18920, 18962, NA, 18850,
NA, NA), class = "Date"), V10 = structure(c(18879, 18911,
18857, 18904, 18974, NA, 18890, 18884, 18815, 18808, 18844,
18850, 18897, NA, 18921, 18963, 18960, 18851, NA, 18876), class = "Date"),
V11 = structure(c(NA, 18912, 18858, 18905, 18975, 18960,
18891, 18885, 18816, 18809, NA, 18851, 18898, 18974, NA,
NA, 18961, NA, 18932, 18877), class = "Date"), V12 = structure(c(NA,
18913, NA, 18906, 18976, 18961, 18892, 18886, NA, NA, NA,
NA, 18899, 18975, NA, NA, 18962, NA, 18933, 18878), class = "Date"),
V13 = structure(c(NA, 18914, NA, 18907, 18977, 18962, 18893,
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18900, 18976, NA, NA, 18963, NA, 18934,
18879), class = "Date"), V14 = structure(c(18883, NA, NA,
NA, NA, 18963, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18848, NA, NA, 18977, 18925,
18967, NA, 18855, 18935, NA), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA,
20L), class = "data.frame")

```
head(T0range)
  Included.y         V1         V2         V3         V4         V5         V6   V7         V8         V9        V10        V11        V12        V13  V14
1          3       <NA>       <NA> 2021-11-29 2021-11-30 2021-12-01 2021-12-02 <NA>       <NA>       <NA> 2021-12-06 2021-12-07 2021-12-08 2021-12-09 <NA>
2          4       <NA> 2021-09-06 2021-09-07 2021-09-08 2021-09-09       <NA> <NA>       <NA> 2021-09-13 2021-09-14 2021-09-15 2021-09-16       <NA> <NA>
3          5 2021-09-13 2021-09-14 2021-09-15 2021-09-16       <NA>       <NA> <NA> 2021-09-20 2021-09-21 2021-09-22 2021-09-23       <NA>       <NA> <NA>
4          6 2021-11-15 2021-11-16 2021-11-17 2021-11-18       <NA>       <NA> <NA> 2021-11-22 2021-11-23 2021-11-24 2021-11-25       <NA>       <NA> <NA>
5          8 2021-08-02 2021-08-03 2021-08-04 2021-08-05       <NA>       <NA> <NA> 2021-08-09 2021-08-10 2021-08-11 2021-08-12       <NA>       <NA> <NA>
6          9       <NA> 2021-11-08 2021-11-09 2021-11-10 2021-11-11       <NA> <NA>       <NA> 2021-11-15 2021-11-16 2021-11-17 2021-11-18       <NA> <NA>
```

I cannot seem to find a way to save the 'Included.y' column in the df1 and I think that it would be relatively easy... so i really hope that you can help me out!

Thanks so much in advance

Comment: You should use `dput(head(T0range))` to provide the code to create the sample data `head(T0range)`, which will be more convient for us to help you.

Comment: Hi Peace Wang, i added the dput (for the whole df). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(tidyr)
 
T0Range %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Included.y) %>% 
  mutate(name = factor(name, levels = paste0("V", 1:14), ordered = TRUE))%>% 
  arrange(value, name) %>% 
  group_by(value) %>%
  slice_head(n = 12) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value) -> df1

df1
```