# Date occurs an x amount of times, move on to the next available date per ID number

Tags: r, dataframe

A couple of days ago I posted the following question:

[Occurence of certain date is more than x times, get next available date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66903560/occurence-of-certain-date-is-more-than-x-times-get-next-available-date/66904690?noredirect=1#comment118470713_66904690)

I got a great solution for the dataframe given but this was an example dataset where the dates were in order and the IDs were in order as well (Included.y is the ID variable):

```
dput(T0range)
structure(list(Included.y = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
16, 17, 18, 19, 20), V1 = structure(c(18708, 18708, 18708, 18708, 
18708, 18708, 18709, 18709, 18709, 18709, 18715, 18715, 18715, 
18715, 18715), class = "Date"), V2 = structure(c(18709, 18709, 
18709, 18709, 18709, 18709, 18710, 18710, 18710, 18710, 18716, 
18716, 18716, 18716, 18716), class = "Date"), V3 = structure(c(18710, 
18710, 18710, 18710, 18710, 18710, 18711, 18711, 18711, 18711, 
18717, 18717, 18717, 18717, 18717), class = "Date"), V4 = structure(c(18711, 
18711, 18711, 18711, 18711, 18711, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18718, 18718, 
18718, 18718, 18718), class = "Date"), V5 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_
), class = "Date"), V6 = structure(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), 
    V7 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18715, 18715, 18715, 
    18715, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), class = "Date"), V8 = structure(c(18715, 
    18715, 18715, 18715, 18715, 18715, 18716, 18716, 18716, 18716, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), class = "Date"), V9 = structure(c(18716, 
    18716, 18716, 18716, 18716, 18716, 18717, 18717, 18717, 18717, 
    18723, 18723, 18723, 18723, 18723), class = "Date"), V10 = structure(c(18717, 
    18717, 18717, 18717, 18717, 18717, 18718, 18718, 18718, 18718, 
    18724, 18724, 18724, 18724, 18724), class = "Date"), V11 = structure(c(18718, 
    18718, 18718, 18718, 18718, 18718, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18725, 
    18725, 18725, 18725, 18725), class = "Date"), V12 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), V13 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date"), V14 = structure(c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-15L), class = "data.frame")
```

The solution provided from my first question works perfectly well with this example and gives me the output desired:

```
dput(df1)
structure(list(Included.y = 1:15, V1 = structure(c(18708, 18708, 
18708, 18709, 18709, 18709, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18715, 18715, 
18715), class = "Date"), V2 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 18710, 18710, 18710, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), class = "Date"), 
    V3 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18711, 
    18711, 18711, NA, NA, NA), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-15L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

However, this solution does not consider the ID variable at all, only the order of the dates. The above solution would work perfectly if the column of the participant ID would be next to it.
I need the ID column because in reality, some IDs will not be included and the dates will not be in order. Example of the real data (first 20 rows):

dput:

```
structure(list(Included.y = c(72, 108, 165, 205, 472, 530, 574, 
750, 1, 2, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47), V1 = structure(c(18918, 
18918, NA, NA, 18919, 18918, NA, NA, 18793, NA, NA, NA, 18800, 
NA, NA, 18841, 18953, NA, NA, NA), class = "Date"), V2 = structure(c(18919, 
18919, 18918, NA, 18920, 18919, NA, NA, 18794, NA, 18904, NA, 
18801, NA, NA, 18842, 18954, NA, NA, 18890), class = "Date"), 
    V3 = structure(c(18920, 18920, 18919, 18918, 18921, 18920, 
    NA, NA, 18795, 18911, 18905, NA, 18802, NA, 18820, 18843, 
    18955, 18855, 18911, 18891), class = "Date"), V4 = structure(c(18921, 
    18921, 18920, 18919, NA, 18921, 18981, 18981, NA, 18912, 
    18906, 18974, NA, 18932, 18821, 18844, 18956, 18856, 18912, 
    18892), class = "Date"), V5 = structure(c(NA, NA, 18921, 
    18920, NA, NA, 18982, 18982, NA, 18913, 18907, 18975, NA, 
    18933, 18822, NA, NA, 18857, 18913, 18893), class = "Date"), 
    V6 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, 18921, NA, NA, 18983, 18983, 
    NA, 18914, NA, 18976, NA, 18934, 18823, NA, NA, 18858, 18914, 
    NA), class = "Date"), V7 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 18925, 
    NA, 18984, 18984, 18799, NA, NA, 18977, 18806, 18935, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), class = "Date"), V8 = structure(c(18925, 
    18925, NA, NA, 18926, 18925, NA, NA, 18800, NA, NA, NA, 18807, 
    NA, NA, 18848, 18960, NA, NA, NA), class = "Date"), V9 = structure(c(18926, 
    18926, 18925, NA, 18927, 18926, NA, NA, 18801, NA, 18911, 
    NA, 18808, NA, NA, 18849, 18961, NA, NA, 18897), class = "Date"), 
    V10 = structure(c(18927, 18927, 18926, 18925, 18928, 18927, 
    NA, NA, 18802, 18918, 18912, NA, 18809, NA, 18827, 18850, 
    18962, 18862, 18918, 18898), class = "Date"), V11 = structure(c(18928, 
    18928, 18927, 18926, NA, 18928, 18988, 18988, NA, 18919, 
    18913, 18981, NA, 18939, 18828, 18851, 18963, 18863, 18919, 
    18899), class = "Date"), V12 = structure(c(NA, NA, 18928, 
    18927, NA, NA, 18989, 18989, NA, 18920, 18914, 18982, NA, 
    18940, 18829, NA, NA, 18864, 18920, 18900), class = "Date"), 
    V13 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, 18928, NA, NA, 18990, 18990, 
    NA, 18921, NA, 18983, NA, 18941, 18830, NA, NA, 18865, 18921, 
    NA), class = "Date"), V14 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 18932, 
    NA, 18991, 18991, 18806, NA, NA, 18984, 18813, 18942, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

In my desired output, i would like to get all the ids of the participants next to the scheduled dates. Each date should occur a maximum of 3 times:

```
structure(list(Included.y = c(72, 108, 165, 205, 472, 530, 574, 
750, 1, 2, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47), V1 = structure(c(18918, 
18918, NA, NA, 18919, 18918, NA, NA, 18793, NA, NA, NA, 18800, 
NA, NA, 18841, 18953, NA, NA, NA), class = "Date"), V2 = structure(c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18904, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 18890), class = "Date"), V3 = structure(c(NA, NA, 
18919, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18911, NA, NA, NA, NA, 18820, 
NA, NA, 18855, 18911, NA), class = "Date"), V4 = structure(c(NA, 
NA, NA, 18919, NA, NA, 18981, 18981, NA, NA, NA, 18974, NA, 18932, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), class = "Date"), V5 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), V6 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), V7 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), V8 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), V9 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), V10 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
), V11 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), V12 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), V13 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), V14 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -20L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Note that if all 14 available dates for one participant are all already fully booked (so each date has already been filled up by previous participants), all columns would remain NA.

I really hope i made this clear enough and otherwise please let me know what I can do to make it more clear. Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to provide the solution as illustrated in the question.

There may well be more elegant ways to achieve this with vectorised code; but I could only get a solution using loops.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)

# Copy of original data, rowids added to allow for arranging processed data into original order later.

df0 <- 
  df %>% 
  rowid_to_column() %>% 
  select(rowid, Included.y)

# prepare data in long format for loop to extract rows by date and id as required

df1 <- 
  df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Included.y, names_to = "vis", values_to = "date")%>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  arrange(date, vis, Included.y)

# initialise tibble for data that fits the criteria

df2 <- tibble(Included.y = rep(NA_real_, nrow(df)),
              vis = rep(NA_character_, nrow(df)),
              date = as.Date(rep(NA_real_, nrow(df)), format = "%Y-%m-%d"))

# counter and loops (for loop working through all options to feed the while loop which collects the final arrangement of ids and dates)

i <- 1

while(i <= nrow(df)){
  
  
  for(j in seq_len(nrow(df1))){
    
 # this line is the meat of the code which basically says no more than three dates to be used and each person only has one date. 
   
    if(sum(df2$date == df1$date[j], na.rm = TRUE) <= 2 & sum(df2$Included.y == df1$Included.y[j], na.rm = TRUE) == 0){
      
      df2[i, ] <- df1[j, ]
      
      i <-  i + 1
    }
    
  }
}


# manipulate the data for presentation in format similar to original data including row order

df3 <- 
  df2 %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = vis, values_from = date, names_sort = TRUE) %>% 
  left_join(df0) %>% 
  arrange(rowid) %>% 
  select(-rowid)
#> Joining, by = "Included.y"

head(df3)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#>   Included.y V1         V2         V3         V4        
#>        <dbl> <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>    
#> 1         72 2021-10-18 NA         NA         NA        
#> 2        108 2021-10-18 NA         NA         NA        
#> 3        165 NA         NA         2021-10-19 NA        
#> 4        205 NA         NA         NA         2021-10-19
#> 5        472 2021-10-19 NA         NA         NA        
#> 6        530 2021-10-18 NA         NA         NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Hello Peter, this solution works very well, even with a dataframe consisting of about 1000 participants. I have ran into an issue and while loops are definitely not my area of expertise.. I have tested the loop now with about 850 participants with dates ranging from now until 2 months from now. I would assume that some participants cannot get a date assigned to them because of the short range. While running the loop in this example, it keeps on running because (i believe) the variable i will never reach the nrow((df). Is there a way to account for this? Thanks!

Comment: Without understanding the nature of your actual data it would be difficult to say how best to deal with this. How many rows do you have in your actual dataset? The most likely case is, as you say, if some participants cannot get a date assigned then I agree the loop would not end. This becomes another question! If you can narrow down when the code hangs so you can identify the conditions that cause the loop to hang then the code could be adjusted to manage this.

Comment: The data is about 840 rows. The seq_len of df1 is 6688 and it seems to be stuck when the variable i is  at 625. I adjusted the `while(i <= nrow(df_T0))` to `while(i <= 100)` but then the outcome of df3 contains NULL values and the dates as numeric values instead of a date format. df3 gives the following warning messages: Warning message:
Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
* Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
* Use `values_fn = length` to identify where the duplicates arise
* Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates

Comment: Best bet is to find a small chunk of the data that gives these problems, check the data is different from the data in this question may be the data need cleaning or the loop needs adjusting to allow for cases which the current minimal dataset does not account for.